# Convert integer to words

Tags: r

For the purpose of styling data visualizations, I'd like to be able to display an integer using words (e.g.

> "Two thousand and seventeen"

) rather than digits (e.g. `2017`).

As an example of what I'm looking for, here's a quick function that works for a small, scalar integer:

```
int_to_words <- function(x) {

                   index <- as.integer(x) + 1
                   words <- c('zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four',
                              'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine',
                              'ten')
                   words[index]
}


int_to_words(5)
```

Comment: I edited out one sentence of your question because it's against SO rules to ask for library recommendations. Anyway, have you seen this one (goes in the other direction but is easily reversed) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332463/convert-written-number-to-number-in-r ?

Comment: Well I already gave you the solution linked above and another one in my answer below, but vague or specific it's just against the rules to ask for library recommendations. Not a big deal, it's easily edited out of the question and people can still answer with libraries. Rules are just rules, you know?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Use the `as.english` function from the 'english' package:

```
library(english)

as.english(2017)
```

**Option 2:**

Use the `replace_number` function from the 'qdap' package.

```
library(qdap)

replace_number(2017)
```

**Option 3:**

Use the `numbers_to_words` function from the 'xfun' package.

```
library(xfun)

numbers_to_words(2017)
```

Answer (score 5):

Asides from the function I linked in the comments, here's another solution from a GitHub gist:

```
source("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hack-r/22104543e2151519c41a8f0ce042b31c/raw/01731f3176b4ee471785639533d38eda4790ab77/numbers2words.r")

numbers2words(0)
```

> [1] "zero"

```
numbers2words(5)
```

> [1] "five"

```
numbers2words(50000)
```

> [1] "fifty thousand"

```
numbers2words(50000000000000)
```

> [1] "fifty trillion"