# How to replace numbers into a word in R

Tags: r

I have a question with regards too; how do I replace numbers like, 1,2,300,400,5000,6000, etc... into a word, for example, 'numbertag'.

The data consists of tweets related to cryptocurrency.

For example;

Text tweet:

"bitcoin smashes through $5000usd barrier, pending bitcoingold fork.

With the code, the tweet has to be;

"bitcoin smashes through $numbertagusd barrier, pending bitcoingold fork.

Best regards,

Otto

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46652277/5028841

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this what you want but you can replace numbers in string with `gsub`

```
x <- c("1212", "121neco", "abc")
gsub("[1-9]+", "numbertag", x)
```

result

```
[1] "numbertag"     "numbertagneco" "abc"
```

if you need to replace them for actual word see @jbgruber comment below your question